# Disabling the WS_CAPTION flag does not work for chrome apps opened as window anymore

Tags: windows, windows-10, google-chrome, autohotkey

For years I've been using the ahk script below to disable the WS_CAPTION (long 0x00C00000) flag on Windows 10 applications windows in order to make their title bars invisible. The most common case of usage is for chrome apps opened as window.

```
LWIN & MButton::
MouseGetPos,,, WinUMID
WinSet, Style, -0xC00000, ahk_id %WinUMID%
```

I'm not sure if it's because of my Windows update or Chrome update, but this does not work for chrome apps opened as windows anymore. It still does work for other applications, though. I'm pretty sure there is no problem with my script, because I never change it. Also, my AutoHotKey didn't update, so I guess there is no problem with it as well. I've filled a bug report for chrome (I think they don't provide reporters an url), even though I'm not sure it's their problem. Does anyone also have this issue or know what could cause it?

As asked by [3D1T0R](https://superuser.com/users/776028/3d1t0r), here's a screenshot of a current window that this script used to work on.
[image: screenshot of a current window that this script used to work on]

Thank you very much.

Comment: What versions are you running of Windows and Chrome? (For Windows, please supply Edition, Version and Build #.) Also, is there any chance you could add a screenshot of a window that you would do this to?

Comment: Chrome stable channel 67.0.3396.87 64bits

Comment: Windows 10 Pro Version 1803 Build 17134.112

Comment: Is this your problem : [Google will end support for Chrome apps](https://www.theverge.com/2016/8/19/12555052/google-shutting-down-chrome-apps)? The article says: "come early 2018, you'll no longer be able to load Chrome apps".

Comment: @harrymc not at all. it's not real apps. You can drag and drop a url to the chrome://apps page and check the "open as a window" option. That's what I mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by deactivating the #windows10-custom-titlebar flag at chrome://flags and restarting the browser. Thanks everyone who replied.

Comment: Worked for me in Chrome/Windows 10. Allows removing title bar on chrome windows, which is great for arranging YouTube TV windows. Disable the flag, restart chrome, load YouTube TV with a command like `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --profile-directory=Default --app=https://tv.youtube.com/ --enable-kiosk-mode`, then use AutoHotKey script to perfrom a `WinSet, Style, -0xC00000, A` on the Window. A bit complicated, but gets me borderless video windows with no wasted screen space!

Comment: Update: the flag does not exist anymore, but the argument `--disable-features=Windows10CustomTitlebar` did the job for a while. Right now, not even the argument works. I don't know a way to fix this as for today. I'll comment back if I managed to make it work again.

Answer (score 1):

I used
[Window Detective](https://sourceforge.net/projects/windowdetective/)
to select the Chrome window (normal window and not an app).

This tool allows to edit the window's styles, so I used it to delete
the WS_CAPTION style a couple of times.

The result upon clicking the *Set* button was a flicker, and sometimes
the Chrome window itself moved slightly on the screen, but the caption stayed.

Upon re-examining the style after the change,
I found that the WS_CAPTION style has
been returned to the Chrome window.

My conclusion is that recent versions of Chrome now detect the change
in style and reset it immediately back to what it was before.

I am afraid that you are up against Chrome not allowing such changes.
If I am right, you may need to move to another browser,
or to accept that the caption is unavoidable
(at least until some future time when maybe this will change back).
A lame alternative would be to move the Chrome window so that the caption
is positioned off-screen.

You may raise the question in the Chrome forums, asking for this to be reversed,
but your chances may be slim.

Comment: I wish i could find the exact chromium commit where this has been broken, but the repository is super active. Another alternative may be to reinstall an old version and stick to it.

Comment: If you are into Chrome sources, try to search for WS_CAPTION.

Comment: I guess you're having the bounty since it's the only option besides keeping it open